# Azure Function (ServiceBus) System.Private.CoreLib Error (Works locally)

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

When I run my Azure functions locally they work like a charm.
But when I publish and run them in the cloud I get following error:

> [Error] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Alert. Function.PowerBI: Abandom message in AzureFunction.PowerBi.

Running a function called Alert in a Function called PowerBi.
Is there a way, maybe in Kudu to see the actually error or how should i interpret an error in

> System.Private.CoreLib

Code:

```
    [FunctionName("Alert")]
    public static async Task Alert([ServiceBusTrigger(Topic.Alert, Subscription.PowerBi, Connection = "servicebusconnectionstring")] Message message, TraceWriter log)
    {
        if (!MessageHandler.Validate(message, Subscription.PowerBi))
            return;

        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
        var messageCounter = message.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount;

        try
        {
            var alert = Validator.ValidateCloudAlert(json);
            if (alert != null)
            {
                var powerBiAlert = alert.ToPowerBiAlert();
                var result = await PowerBiService.AddRow(powerBiAlert);
                if (!result)
                    throw new PowerBiCommandException($"PowerBiService.AddRows returned value: {result}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            EventLogger.LoggException("Function.PowerBi.Alert", e, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Messsage", json } });
            if (messageCounter >= 5)
            {
                EventLogger.LoggEvent("DeadLetterQueue", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Function", "Function.PowerBi.Alert" }, { "Messsage", json } });
                await QueueService.SendAsync(Queue.Deadletter, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CloudAlert>(json), Topic.Alert, Subscription.PowerBi);
            }
            else
                throw new MessageAbandonException($"Abandom message in AzureFunction.PowerBi");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can set up Application Insights to monitor and search for errors in your Function executions. If there is still insufficient details, kindly open an issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/new and we will investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following package that was included made the Azure Function to stop working:

> PackageReference Include="System.Dynamic.Runtime" Version="4.3.0"

Is there a way to find out this more easy, this time I just removed line of code until I found out what the issue was. Very time consuming. Even with your suggestion about using Application Insights (which I do) it's quite hard to find the real issue. I just had to spend some time and see what row it happend to and tried to remove all nugets related to that until I found the issue.